# How to get the correspond listItem from the last major version of a file via CSOM

Tags: development, csom

I am trying to get the last major version of a file in a sharepoint-list by using CSOM with the following Code:

```
        var web = clientContext.Web;
        var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
        var listitem = list.GetItemById(id);
        clientContext.Load(listitem,
            x => x.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
            x => x.File.Versions,
            x => x.File.MajorVersion,
            x => x.File.MinorVersion
            );
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem oldItem = null;
        if (listitem.File.MinorVersion == 0)
        {
            clientContext.Load(listitem);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            oldItem = listitem;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (FileVersion version in listitem.File.Versions)
            {

                if (version.VersionLabel == listitem.File.MajorVersion.ToString() + ".0")
                {
                    String versionUrl = listitem.File.ServerRelativeUrl + "?PageVersion=" + version.ID;
                    File versionFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(versionUrl);
                    clientContext.Load(versionFile, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    oldItem = versionFile.ListItemAllFields;
                }
            }
        }
```

If the current version is a major version, there is no problem to load the properties of the desired listItem.
Unfortunately if the current version is a minor version the File.ListItemAllFields-Property does not contain 
any values. 
Does somebody know what i have to change to get the listItem of the last major version of a file if the current version is a
minor one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The current version is the base URL, without the /_vti_history/nnn/ part of the URL. With respect to versions there is x Versions + 1 which is the current URL, not to be confused with the current published.